# undefined method Joomla\Registry\Registry::getValue()

Tags: joomla, getvalue

I'm having an issue with a Joomla site, It was recently upgraded to Joomla 3.0 but now the home page hows the error "undefined method Joomla\Registry\Registry::getValue()", the only issue is it does not tell me which files are throwing this error.

I have run a file search in cPanel and a grep at command line to find any files with "getValue" in them but all responses are 0. I've even checked the database, just in case a previous developer put it in there but I have nothing.

I've searched the web, checked error logs, disabled plugins and pretty much bashed my skull against the wall for the last week to no avail.

Can anyone help?
I working on the updated site here: http://dev.hershmanlegal.com/

Answer (score 0):

In the backend of your Joomla site, try going to **System > Global Configuration > Server**, change the error reporting to Maximum and see if you get more details about the source of the problem.

[image: Joomla Error Reporting]

If still no joy, check your server error logs.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I tired both, there is nothing. Other pages load though, only the home page shows the error. It's really confusing.

Comment: @AndrewCole, If you haven't already, you could try and narrow down the source of the problem, and knowing it only happens on the home page helps somewhat.  You could change your site template to say Protostar and check your home page, this would confirm whether or not the issue is related to your template. If you don't have any luck there, systematically disabling all the components, modules and plugins that are used on the home page would hopefully find the culprit. Good luck in your hunt.

Comment: FWIW, have you tried duplicating the home page at another location then adding a fresh menu link to it, or rebuilding all your menu links? And making sure your site cache has been cleared. Oddly dev.hershmanlegal.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2&Itemid=3 works but dev.hershmanlegal.com doesn't.

Comment: I have disabled the theme and the nav now shows, so I can navigate to the pages and see that most work except the contact and home page but the contact page I can fix. The problem is, I did not build the sit, I was brought in after the update, so I have no idea which plugins load where and they have about 50 in the database.

Comment: It's difficult to troubleshoot this more from a distance. I think it's less likely the problem is caused by a plugin, I would focus on either a component, module or the site template.  If you can't pinpoint it by temporarily disabling extensions, consider rebuilding your home page.

Comment: I never did figure it out. IN the end I talked them in to rebuilding on another CMS which won't break when updating versions.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewCole, that's too bad you couldn't find the cause of the problem, good that you found a long term solution though.